# Textmate C++ Input execution

Tags: c++, input, textmate

In textmate, is there a way to run a c++ program in command line fashion?
For simplicity sake, say I have a c++ program that prompts for an input, and therefore produces some sort of output, is there a way to run the program from textmate so that it will allow for an entry of an input?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It used to be there: http://blog.macromates.com/2009/interactive-input

And now it ain't.